# S3 policy that allows uploads to subfolder only from user's Cognito `sub`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-access-policy

### Goals:

- Limit uploads to specific set of subdirectories which helps the backend identify the reason for the upload: `/avatar/...`, `/cover/...`
- Have a way to identify the upload's cognito user
- Prevent other users overriding content in this user's subfolder

With that in mind, I can't figure out how to limit the user ability to upload only to subfolder with name derived from user's cognito `sub` identifier. Or any other string from which I can identify and fetch the user from the cognito pool.

Example: `avatar/${aws:cognito-sub}/filename`

I found `aws:userid` in the docs but it [refers to](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html):

> role id:caller-specified-role-name
>
> where role id is the unique id of the role and the
>   caller-specified-role-name is specified by the RoleSessionName
>   parameter passed to the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity request.

More context: The upload is handled in a lambda. Lambda transforms the image, but then needs to save the transformations in a different s3 and reference them to the user inside dynamodb.

Comment: If you use Cognito then you can do this (I think). You can mention resources  in Cognito roles with cognito sub as parameter. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html

Comment: @agent420 the cognito sub parameter in the policy sadly refers to group of users federated identity instead of user sub